# Lightning Component throws error like 'Sorry to interrupt'

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I created a lightning component and added to the Case Page Layout, this lightning component when clicked should create a Contract and associate with the Case. The lightning component is like below

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId" access="global"  controller="createContractLightningComp">
    <aura:attribute name="createContract" type="Case" default="{'sobjectType':'Case'}"/>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Create Contract" onclick="{!c.createContract}"  />      
   <lightning:spinner aura:id="mySpinner" alternativeText="Processing.." title="Processing.." variant="brand" size="large" class="slds-hide"/> 
</aura:component>
```

And the helper class is like

```
({
    createContract_helper : function(c,e,h) {
    var spinner = c.find("mySpinner");
    $A.util.removeClass(spinner, "slds-hide");
    var set_action1 = c.get("c.createContract");
    set_action1.setParams({caseId: c.get('v.recordId')});
    set_action1.setCallback(this, function(result)
    {
        var returnData = result.getReturnValue();
        if (result.getState() === 'SUCCESS')
            {
                $A.util.addClass(spinner, "slds-hide");
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    message: 'The Contract has been created!' ,
                    type: 'success',
                    mode: 'pester'
                });
                toastEvent.fire(); 
            }                 
            else if(result.getState() === 'ERROR')
            {
                $A.util.addClass(spinner, "slds-hide");
                var errors = result.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        $A.get("e.force:showToast")
                        .setParams({
                            type: 'error',
                            mode: 'pester',
                            message: errors[0].message }).fire();                       
                    }}}
        $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(set_action1);       
},})
```

Also the Apex Class is like

```
public class createContractLightningComp {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String createContract(String caseId){
        
        List<Case> case_recs = [SELECT id,Contract__c,Category_Contracts__c,AccountId, ContactId from Case WHERE Id = :caseId];

        String recordType;
        String msg;        
        Boolean CDA_Two_Way;
        
       for (Case rec : case_recs)
        {
            try{      
                if(rec.Category_Contracts__c=='SOW'){
                        recordType='XXXXXXXXXXXX'; 
                    }
                    else if(rec.Category_Contracts__c=='T&C')
                    {
                        recordType='YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY'; 
                    } 
                    
                    Contract cc;
                    cc = new Contract(AccountId = rec.AccountId,Contact__c = rec.ContactId,RecordtypeId =recordType, Status = 'Pending');
                    insert cc;                         
                    
                    if (cc.id != null)
                    {
                        System.debug('@@Inserted ID '+ cc.id);
                        rec.Contract__c = cc.id;
                        update rec;                        
                    }
                    
                    msg = ' Success The Contract has been created';
                    return msg;                   
            }
            catch(DmlException e) 
            {
                for (Integer i = 0; i < e.getNumDml(); i++) {
                    msg =+ e.getDmlMessage(i) +  '\n' ; 
                    System.debug('getDmlFieldNames=' + e.getDmlFieldNames(i));
                    System.debug('getDmlMessage=' + e.getDmlMessage(i));  
                }
                throw new AuraHandledException(msg);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
            }
            finally { }      
        }
        return msg;
    }
}
```

But whenever the lightning component button is clicked it just puts the spinner on the page and I get the Sorry to Interrupt error

[image]

I tried to debug just the Apex Class everything working as expected though. Can anyone please help me with this issue.

Comment: Can you please add the technical stuff from the error popup and also check the console log if there is something additional helpful error message?

Comment: @sanketkumar I couldnt expand the Technical Stuff. But when I tried to put the debugger and tried to click the button on F12 mode I see that the helper.js is executed again and again

Comment: Can you also add the controller of the aura component? It's interesting to see helper executing again and again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your **JS controller method and apex controller method name is same** `createContract`. That's why its going in an infinite loop.

E.g. from controller its going to helper, from helper again controller and again helper...